# Disabling specific rows in dojo dgrid

Tags: javascript, dojo, dgrid

Is it possible to disable specific rows displayed in a dojo dgrid?
I want to still display them, but not allow the user to select/edit them.

Let's say that out of 10 rows that my dgrid has, I want to disable 3.

Cheers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The editor plugin supports a `canEdit` function on the column definition object in cases where `editOn` is specified.  This function receives the data item for the row, and the value to be rendered (e.g. as determined by the column's `field` or its `get` function).  Returning `false` from this should result in the cell for that particular row not being editable.

The Selection mixin supports an `allowSelect` method which receives a row object (i.e. as produced by `grid.row(...)`), and determines whether that row is selectable based on its return value.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the editable property of the col as false. If you are declaring grid programitically then in  you can specify this. In case of declarative, then need to specify in layout then with col definition you need to give *editable: false*

Comment: Yes, but it would still be selectable, no? I want to disable the specific row's selection...and preferably grey it out - like in a button, for instance.

Comment: There is no `editable` property on column definitions in dgrid.  The presence or lack of the editor plugin determines whether columns are editable.  Also, the question was about row-specific enabling/disabling.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible. If the `selection-mixin` & `editor-plugin` are not 'mixed in', the default dgrid will have the desired functionality. 
If you need to provide selection programmatically but not by user or depending on some condition, you can use the `dgrid/Selection` mixin and have

```
selectionMode : 'none'
```

similarly you can set

```
editable: false
```

if you need the editor plugin & want to disable for some reason/condition.

Comment: Updated my question to be clearer - I want to disable specific rows...not all rows!